# -0.5px letter-spacing in CSS not working in Chrome

Tags: css, letter-spacing

I have @font-face installed and have reduced letter spacing by

```
letter-spacing: -0.5px
```

This works well in Firefox, but doesn't seem to work in Chrome. How can I get the negative letter-spacing to work in Chrome?

Comment: Why not just use -1px or integers? I guess half of a pixel doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. -1px is too compressed (squashed) for the font type.

Comment: maybe this article will help you understand some stuff [My (just-discovered) workaround to the WebKit letter-spacing bug](http://blog.room34.com/archives/4986)

Comment: Thanks Monica - this resolved my issue